# Changing text of textblock from another page

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

Messages.xaml

```
<TextBlock  x:Name="txt_count_unreads" Text="0"  />
```

App.xaml
check messages...and

```
Messages mm = new Messages();

 Messages.txt_count_unreads.Text = unreads.ToString();
```

But text not changing?What's wrong?

Comment: You appear to be creating a new view in a local variable, but there is no code to actually display it. Can you show more code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each XAML page, along with its code behind page, are a class, having the same name as the XAML file. On Windows Phone 7 all such page classes have the common base class [`PhoneApplicationPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). When you navigate to a new page, the phone framework creates an ***instance*** of that class and loads it into the [`PhoneApplicationFrame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402543%28VS.92%29.aspx).

So, creating an instance of your page class randomly somewhere in your code, and changing properties on that instance, will not work!

You should make the `unreads` property available to the `Messages` class (or pass it in the query string while navigating to the `Messages` page) and then set the `TextBlock` text within the `Messages` constructor.

---

This is really basic stuff you need to know before ever starting to write code for a phone app. I'm not trying to discourage you, but you will benefit a great deal if you spend a day or two reading a book. Charles Petzold has a [free book](http://charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html) that starts of with very basic applications and moves on to more advanced topics.